# File was deleted BUT actual file is not. (sounds wrong)

Tags: java, android, file, android-alertdialog

How to actually delete the physical file? The below code deleted the file successfully (upon reloading the file list, the file is gone). BUT, when I open the sdcard through "PC" explorer the files are still present.

```
public boolean delete(String filename){
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "/" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/";
    File file = new File(path + filename );
    return file.delete()
}
```

I tried to add the media scanner but still no good. below is for media scanner:

```
private void mMakeFilePublic(File file) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mContext,
            new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your developed code
You have to give permission if you are using >1.6 SDK

**uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

Also you can try another method

```
public abstract boolean deleteFile (String name)
```

The above may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: deleteFile(String name) is for deleting internals files? I tried it earlier and it does not accept seperator ("/"). The permission was already added earlier.